# Twilio implementation error occured [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter, twilio

I installed Twilio sdk library using composer. After uploaded to my project and test it out, I received this error when the function is loaded.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/my-codeigniter-project-domain/application/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Client.php on line 195

**Project Environment**

- CodeIgniter 3 framework
- PHP 5.6
- twilio ^6.1

My code is something like this :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

class FreeSignupController extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function send_sms_demo(){
        // Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
        $sid = 'my-acc-sid';
        $token = 'auth-token';
        $client = new Client($sid, $token);

        // Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
        $client->messages->create(
            // the number you'd like to send the message to
            'phone-number-here',
            array(
                'from' => 'my-twilio-phone-number',
                'body' => "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!"
            )
        );
    }

}
```

In twilio **Client.php** error is at this line

```
public function request(string $method, string $uri, array $params = [], array $data = [], array $headers = [], string $username = null, string $password = null, int $timeout = null): \Twilio\Http\Response {
```

It's my first time using Twilio so I'm unsure what's going on.

Comment: What's your PHP version?

Comment: *PHP 7 adds support for return type declarations*, so `null): \Twilio\Http\Response` is invalid for PHP 5.6

Comment: It's also worth noting that from the [manual](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/) *On January 1, 2020, Twilio will no longer support PHP version 5.X, 7.0, and 7.1 via this helper library*

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the info guys.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `: \Twilio\Http\Response`.